# Problems with using potential dividers to scale 220V AC mains to 0 to 5V

Tags: microcontroller, power, signal, noise

I want to measure the 220V grid voltage using a microcontroller. I can either use a transformer to step down the voltage to 6V rms and use potential divider and dc bias to bring the voltage to uController friendly 0 to 5V range. Or I can use potential dividers without the transformers.

What problems will I run into if I use potential dividers to divide the grid voltage (and add DC bias) and interface them directly with my microcontroller without any isolation?

Edit:
I want to understand the implication of a design with no isolation. I am guessing electrocution is only a problem during production and testing. And it goes away once the circuit is nicely packaged in a plastic container.

Edit2:
What I am designing is a minimalist watt meter that only communicates wirelessly via wifi. Only thing exposed out will be a socket to plug the appliances in.

Comment: You said it, no isolation and potential for electrocution.

Comment: Yes, but what are the implications of no isolation, except for electrocution.

Comment: Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Andyaka kindly reread the updated question.

Comment: Maybe: build something that detects when the mains v is over some threshold, say 100v, and get this (digital) signal to your uC through an optocoupler? The waveform is sinusoidal, so you can compute the mains rms and phase from this.

Comment: What are you using to measure current?

Comment: @Andyaka Hall effect sensor.

Comment: If using a hall effect device for the current you have isolation at this point therefore, I'd use an ADI device that can provide both digital and power isolation to an ADC that is floated up to the live supply potential resistor.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to completely avoid designing a device that is directly coupled to the AC mains. There is the inherent safety issue to be considered but there are others as well.

1. Making a product that is not isolated makes some challenges in device packaging to make sure than no user accessible controls or interface points will be exposed to mains voltages.
2. Since you are making a measurement device there is all likelihood that you will want to attach another device via a cable that has GND return lines in it. Without isolation you will expose the device on the end of the cable to the mains connection in your device.
3. During development when you are trying to download, test and debug software in your MCU any USB or JTAG pods that connected to an non isolated circuit will expose the mains hazard to the supporting development computer.

Overall best recommendation - Do not use a direct coupled to mains type design.

Answer (score 0):

Sure using a transformer on the mains is nice and safe .If you are tight for space you could use a VCO that has a frequency that is proportional to the instantanious value of rectified mains.The discrete VCO drove a garden variety cheap optocoupler with a LED in series .The duty cycle of the pulse in the KHz range was made to be much less than 50% to avoid wasting power.A work associate wrote code for the micro to count the pulses from the output of the opto.The veroboard for this looked a bit bitty but when it was cadded it was really small and cheap and as safe as a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

If your case really is user-tamper-proof, the worst thing that can happen for mains-connected (e.g. divider) design is a fried MCU.

Such designs are not unheard of. Here's one from Freescale: [MK30X Single-Phase Electricity Meter Reference Design](http://www.freescale.com/products/wireless-connectivity/2.4-ghz-wireless-solutions/mk30x-single-phase-electricity-meter-reference-design:RDMK30XSPEM) which can communicate through Zigbee.

The MCU is mains connected, through a divider for voltage and shunt for current measurement. Some bus outputs (e.g. RS232) are opto-coupled for isolation. Their Zigbee (daughterboard) plugs into the I2C bus of this MCU but that port is *not* said to be [opto]isolated from the mains.

Also the JTAG port is not mains-isolated either, and for that one they explicitly warn about shock potential. So yeah, it's not inconceivable to make something like this... Service personnel beware.

Finally given that you say in another (more recent) question here that your EE skills are rusty... THIS (MAINS WATTMETER) IS NOT A PROJECT FOR THE INEXPERIENCED.